# Validating a contact name in python

Tags: python, django, dictionary

Suppose I have three fields in my CSV sheet:

**Conditions:**

```
1) If contact Name is not given then the other two will also be not given.    
2) if contact Name is given then:

   a) Both the values would be given
   b) one of the values from Contact Number and Contact Email would be given
```

Possible Scenarios:

```
Case 1:
   Contact Name             Contact Number                 Contact Email
     Adhiraj                  Blank                         adhi@gmail.com
     Adhiraj                  9999999999                    Blank
```

**Output 1:** This should not pop an error as This is a unique contact.

```
Case 2: 
  Contact Name              Contact Number                Contact Email
     Adhiraj                  9819999999                    adhi@gmail.com
     Adhiraj                  9999999999                    adhi@gmail.com
```

**Output 2:** This should result in an error as the first entry and second entry conflicts.

```
Case 3:
  Contact Name              Contact Number                Contact Email
     Adhiraj                  9819999999                   Blank
     Adhiraj                  9999999999                   Blank
```

**Output 3**: No Error

```
Case 4:
  Contact Name              Contact Number                  Contact Email
     Adhiraj                  Blank                          adhi@gmail.com
     Adhiraj                  Blank                          raj@gmail.com
```

**Output 4**: No error

```
Case 5:
  Contact Name              Contact Number                Contact Email
     Adhiraj                  9819999999                   Blank
     Adhiraj                  9819999999                   Blank
```

**Output 5 **: Error

```
Case 6:
  Contact Name              Contact Number                Contact Email
     Adhiraj                  9819999999                   Blank
     Adhiraj                  9819999999                   Blank
     Raman                    9819999999                   Blank
```

**Output 6** : Error for the third row

So, these were the combinations I could think of for this problem statement.

**Possible workarounds:**

1. Can we have a dictionary with keys as **Contact Name - Contact Number - Contact Email** and compare with all the entries that come up in the sheet to the ones present in the dictionary.
2. To create two separate dictionaries for both **Contact Number** and **Contact Email**.

If anyone can please suggest some solutions as well. I am completely baffled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with a dict or list or better with a database (SQL, NoSQL).

dict: as you are aware you don't have unique keys. You can solve this by giving out unique IDs, or make your key a combination of your column values. Though this can get messy. In general I don't see a reason why you'd need a key.

list: An array would be fine if you are looking for a easy solution.

SQL, NoSQL: database queries are optimized for this and is the most clean solution. The former solution you'd still need to write it to a file etc.

---

Example with list:

```
my_list = [
  {"name": "Albert", "number": 1234, "email": None},
  {"name": "Albert", "number": 1234, "email": "Albert@emailprovider.com"}
]

def check_number_identical(my_list):
  for user1 in my_list:
    for user2 in my_list:
      if user1["number"] == user2["number]:
        return True
  return False
```

Comment: Can you please provide with some code as well for better understanding?

Comment: These entries here will be used for creating contacts, so I would not be having entries for the same in the database.

Comment: Edited answer and added an example for doing it via list. Btw Stackoverflow isn't a community where you get finished solutions. You are supposed to provide code and we help at troubleshooting why it does not run, StackOverflow is not for creating a solution.

Comment: Understood. I'll write my code and update the post once again.